# How would I make on_command_error toggleable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a `on_command_error()` event in my discord bot, but sometimes when I'm writing new commands it's just not enough information, how would I make it toggleable? So that if its off it shows the python error and if it's on it would just show a small user friendly error. Here's what I have right now:

```py
@bot.listen()
async def on_command_error(icy, error):
    try:
        await icy.message.delete()
    except:
        pass

    if __ERRORS__ == 0:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='**Error**', description=f'{error}', color=0xff2b2b)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://media.tenor.com/images/fe70a29bb71a79150401c59c8991c4b8/tenor.gif')
        embed.set_footer(text=__footer__)
        await icy.send(embed=embed, delete_after=__deletetime__)

    if __ERRORS__ == 1:
        print(COLOR['RED'], f'| ERROR |',COLOR['YELLOW'],f'{error}', COLOR["DEFAULT"])
```

Comment: Create a command that switches the value of a boolean & check that in the event

Comment: I know but im wondering how to actually show the big error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, you can make a command(s) that switches a variable using the `global` keyword

```py
__ERRORS__ = False

@bot.command()
async def disable(ctx):
    global __ERRORS__
    __ERRORS__ = False

@bot.command()
async def enable(ctx):
    global __ERRORS__
    __ERRORS__ = True

@bot.event()
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if __ERRORS__:
        raise error

    else:
        # Send the embed
```

Comment: raise error raises the default big error right?